# R ggvis - how to color lines in accordance to factor variable

Tags: r, ggvis

I wish to assign a different color to each instance of V1 in

```
dt <- data.table(rep(letters[1:3], 4), 1:12, (1:12)^2 + (-1.3)^(1:12))
```

Best would be to have both points and lines corresponding to same V1 instance in the same color:

```
dt %>% ggvis(~V2, ~V3) %>%
  layer_points(fill = ~factor(V1)) %>%
  layer_lines(stroke = ~factor(V1))
```

[image: "only one line passing through all data points":]

Drawing just the lines without the points doesn't help either:

```
dt %>% ggvis(~V2, ~V3) %>%
  layer_lines(stroke = ~factor(V1))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to get three separate colored lines, one for each `V1` group, you can either move `stroke` into `ggvis` or leave it where it is and group via `group_by(V1)` before `layer_lines`).

Comment: @aosmith, I'm afraid 
    dt %>% ggvis(~V2, ~V3, stroke = ~factor(V1)) %>% layer_lines()
does not draw any lines at all. Did you try it and actually got lines drawn?

The same holds for
    dt %>% ggvis(~V2, ~V3, fill = ~factor(V1)) %>% layer_points() %>%
    group_by(V1) %>% layer_lines()

Comment: Yes, it worked for me (but I was using a data.frame).  Does the help page example in `layer_lines` work for you?  How about if you change `mtcars` to a data.table?